# Distribution fair coin, expectation and variance

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Toss 6 independent fair coins, and let X be the number that comes up heads. Compute $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$.

Is this the negative geometric distribution? (6-x-1 Choose x-1) (1/2)^x (1/2)^(6-x) ?

Then wouldn't it be $E(X)=x(1-1/2)/1/2 $ ? But it is not an actual number.

Am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: It's binomial, not negative geometric.

Comment: Then since it's binomial: $E(X)=6*1/2$ and $Var(X)=6*1/2*1/2$ ?

Comment: That's right. ${}{}$

Comment: Determining the distribution of X is not neede to compute the expectation and the variance of X.